# A monad that unions sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, trees, monads

Suppose we have a monad that maps types of some kind to other types (see below) , and let types be sets. Let $\alpha, \beta$ be types, $\rightarrow$ denote a function between types, and let $a : \alpha$ indicate that $a\hspace{0.2cm}$ (or $b$) is an expression of type $\alpha $.

Suppose $a : \alpha \hspace{0.2cm}$ indicates that $a$ is in the set of $\alpha$'s (for example, the set of truth values, individuals, etc). Thus $a: \alpha \to \beta$ means that $a$ is in the set of functions from $\alpha$ to $\beta$.  Let type $t$ be the type of boolean truth values. Then the powerset monad can be described as on p.286 https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0205026.pdf, as a structure $\thinspace(\mathbb{M}, \eta, \bigstar)\thinspace$, with $\eta$ the unit and $\bigstar$  the binary operation of the monoid) such that:

$$\mathbb{M} \thinspace α = (α → t) \hspace{1cm} ∀α$$
$$η(a) = \{a\} : \mathbb{M} \thinspace α \hspace{1cm} ∀a : α $$
$$m \bigstar k = \bigcup_{a \in m} k(a): \mathbb{M}\thinspace β \hspace{1cm} ∀m : \mathbb{M}\thinspace α,\; k : α → \mathbb{M}\thinspace β . $$

I am looking for a monad which is a little like this, except that $\eta$ applied to an expression $a$ is the singleton containing $a$, but where $\eta(a) \bigstar k$ forms the union set $\{a, \; k\}$, so $\bigstar$ unions together sets. How would I define such a monad, in the kind of format above?

Basically, I'm looking for a monad which allows you to form singleton sets, and then union them together into one set.

$Clarification$: I just wondered whether there is $some$ monad which provides an operation that unions $\{ John \}$ and $\{ sleeps \}$. Perhaps it is not the power set monad, but another monad.

The application I have in mind relates to binary trees in linguistics: consider a binary branching tree, with $\{x\}$ on one branch $B_1$ and $\{k\}$ on the adjacent branch $B_2$. $x∈Dom(k)$ but we have 'lifted' both $x$ and $k$ to their singleton sets (see the picture below). Now we use some function which looks at the node with $\{x\}$ on one branch and $\{k\}$ on the adjacent branch and then forms $\{k,x\}$ on the mother node of $B_1$ and $B_2$, where $k$ for example is a constant of type $\alpha \to \beta$ and $x$ is a constant of type $\alpha$.

---

In the application I am considering, we let $e, t$ and $s$ be any three objects, none of which is an ordered pair, and then the set of types is the smallest set $T$ satisfying: (1) $e, t, s \in T$; (2) $\alpha, \beta \in T$ implies $\alpha \to \beta \in T$. Objects of type $e$ are individuals, objects of type $t$ are Boolean truth values and objects of type $s$ are possible worlds or indices and objects of type $\alpha \to \beta$ are functions from objects of type $\alpha$ to objects of type $\beta$. Then terms of the logic are given a type and the terms denote objects in a domain (a set of things). So a term of type $e$ denotes an object in $D_e$, the domain of individuals, and a term of type $e \to t$ denotes an object in ${D_t}^{D_e}$, the set of functions from individuals to truth values. This is just Church's simply theory of types with an extra type $s$.

---

I believe that the sort of tree I am thinking of can be represented as the power of the two images below, with $\bigstar$ operating first on $\{false, true \}$ (the unary branch) and then $\{false, true\}$ taking the lambda term on the adjacent branch. If someone could confirm this is correct, that would be great.

If I understand correctly, the choice of $false$ and $true$ is not necessitated, though it might be natural in certain circumstances.

[image][image]

Comment: The expression $\{a, k\}$ is ill-typed: `a` is an element, but `k` is a function.
For example, $\{1,3,4\}$ is a set of numbers but $\{1, (x \mapsto \{i \in \mathbb{R}| i \leq x\}) \}$ is a set of what?
Perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: You will presumably need to solve $({\mathbb M}(\alpha)\to t)={\mathbb M}(\alpha)$ for that.

Comment: @ Musa Al-hassy Why can't the set contain different kinds of things? (i.e, normally we can have a set which contains a function and an element.)

Comment: @  მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I wanted to say that most likely your requirement forces to have all kind of things like $\{a,\{b,\{c,d\}\},\{e,\{f,\{g,\{h,k\}\}\}\},...\}$ so that you will need all iterates of the powerset

Comment: What sort of datatype has elements that could be either sets or functions?

Comment: @ David Roberts I don't know

Comment: (While I know that for a foundational set theory we have ZFC as standard, what is it meant by "type" here? Is there an analogous standard foundation based on types? Or the choice of type theory is obviously immaterial for the question?)

Comment: @ Qfwfq In the type theory I work in, we let $e, t$ and $s$ be any three objects, none of which is an ordered pair, and then the set of types is the smallest set $T$ satisfying: (1) $e, t, s \in T$; (2) $\alpha, \beta \in T$ implies $\alpha \to \beta \in T$. Objects of type $e$ are individuals in a higher order logic, objects of type $t$ are Boolean truth values and objects of type $s$ are possible worlds or indices and objects of type $\alpha \to \beta$ are functions from objects of type $\alpha$ to objects of type $\beta$. Then terms of the logic are given a type...

Comment: (continued) , and the terms denote objects in a domain (a set of things). So a term of type $e$ denotes an object in $D_e$, the domain of individuals, and a term of type $e \to t$ denotes an object in ${D_t}^{D_e}$, the set of functions from individuals to truth values.

Comment: I have clarified my question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The powerset monad that you describe already does precisely what you are asking for:

- the unit $\eta$ takes an element and forms a singleton
- the monad multiplication $\mu_A : \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ is union, i.e., $\mu_A(S) = \bigcup_{B \in S} B$.

You presented the monad in another way, using the bind operation $\star$ instead of the monad multiplication. But $\mu$ and $\star$ are expressible in terms of each other. For $M \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $K : A \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ we have
$$M \star K = \bigcup_{x \in M} K(x) = \mu_A(\{K(x) \mid x \in M\})$$
and for $S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ we have
$$\mu_A(S) = \bigcup_{B \in S} B = S \star \mathbf{id}_{\mathcal{P}(A)}.$$

For instance, we can compute the union of two subsets $X, Y \subseteq A$ as
\begin{multline*}
\{\mathbf{false}, \mathbf{true}\}
  \star (\lambda b : \mathbf{bool} \,.\, \mathbf{if}\,b\,\mathbf{then}\,X\,\mathbf{else}\,Y) \\
=
\bigcup \{\mathbf{if}\,b\,\mathbf{then}\,X\,\mathbf{else}\,Y \mid b \in \{\mathbf{false}, \mathbf{true}\} \} =
\bigcup \{X, Y\} = X \cup Y.
\end{multline*}
You might object to my using the set $\{\mathbf{false}, \mathbf{true}\}$ but note that we have to use *something* specific to the monad in question, or else we can only write down expressions that work for all monads, and that will make it impossible to do anything interesting with our monad.
Indeed, an expression which involves only $\star$ and $\eta$, and nothing else specific to the powerset monad, will only ever generate singletons.

The powerset monad is used to model non-determinism in programming. There we usually equip it with an additional operation that allows us to create a non-singleton set. So perhaps this is what you're asking for?

Comment: I don't understand how $S \bigstar \eta_{A}$ is well typed. $S \in  \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ and $\eta_{A} \in A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ but then $\bigstar \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A)) \to [\mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(A)] \to \mathcal{P}(A)$. But the function between $`[\,]'$ is not the type of $\eta_{A}$.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I am looking for, since I want a function which takes two different singleton sets and then forms the union of those two sets. So the function acts on singleton sets.

Comment: Oops, good catch. That $\eta$ should have been the identity function. I hope it type-checks now. I also added an explanation on how to compute the union of two sets.

Comment: I don't understand how $\{\mathbf{false}, \mathbf{true}\} \star (\lambda b : \mathbf{bool} \,.\, \mathbf{if}\,b\,\mathbf{then}\,X\,\mathbf{else}\,Y)$ unions $X$ and $Y$. Could you explain this lambda term? The application I have in mind: consider a binary branching tree, with $\{x \}$ on one branch and $\{k\}$ on the adjacent branch. $x \in Dom(k)$ but we have 'lifted' both x and k to their singleton sets. Now we use some function which looks at the node with  $\{x \}$ on one branch and $\{k\}$ on the adjacent branch and then forms $\{k, x \}$, where $k, x \in TYPE$.

Comment: I have clarified my question above.

Comment: To be very blunt, this is the particular application: we have on one node the singleton containing the constant $John$ of type $e$ and on the other, adjacent node the singleton containing the constant $sleeps$ of type $e \to t$. We want the mother node of these two nodes to be this: $\{John, sleeps \}$, the set containing the two constants. So we want a function $F$ that acts on $\{John\}$ and $\{ sleeps \}$ to produce this.

Comment: It sounds like you've got your types all mixed up. Or you're using sets for something that they shouldn't be used. In any case, that particular problem has nothiing to do with the powerset monad.

Comment: How? I'm just understanding types like Church in the simple theory of types. We have constants of various types and those constants receive as an interpretation a member of some set. We say $c$ is of type $e$ and this means that the interpretation of the constant $c$ is a member of the set of individuals. That is how Church and Henkin and Montague used types  that's how I am using them.

Comment: I just wondered whether there is $some$ monad which provides an operation that unions $\{ John \}$ and $\{ sleeps \}$. Perhaps it is not the power set monad, but another monad

Comment: Even a monad which provided operations to get from the constant $john$ and the constant $sleeps$ (and not their singletons) to $\{John, sleeps \}$ would be $super$ useful for my linguistic research!

Comment: But it is the powerset monad (or even the finite powerset monad), as I keep trying to explain. I put in extra explanation about how $X$ and $Y$ get unioned together. Basically, I just unfolded the definitions.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just a mere linguist who dabbles in some maths occasionally :)

Comment: Ok, so I will use the lower of the two trees in the picture above. As far as I understand, this is correct (given adjacent branches are interpreted via function application).

Comment: Reading your question again, I see you don't even need a monad. You *claim* that you have an argument $x$ and a function $k$ and that you want to form the set $\{x, k\}$, but in reality you have just two *symbols* $x$ and $k$ that you want to join into a set. Well, that's no monad, that's a *monoid*, and it's simply the monoid of (finite) sets equipped with the union operation. This whole question seems to be off the mark.

Comment: Ok, but I am working in a context where binary trees can only be interpreted via function application. The attraction of monads for linguists, as the article linked to shows, is that they allow us to define other modes of composition in addition to function application, without having to associate an extra rule that states how to interpret binary branching trees. So yes, we could stipulate that some binary branches could be interpreted via union, but this would be to stipulate an additional compositional rule. I would prefer just to have a monad that can do this

Comment: Binary branching trees can be interpreted in monoids quite easily, and that is in fact quite general. After all, a monad is a special case of a monoid.

Comment: Ah, but a monoid is a monad. So we can just use the bind of this monad. I wouldn't know how, though

Comment: Ok, but in the linguistic theories I work in, binary branching trees are only allowed to be interpreted via a limited set of operations (function application being the primary one). So the union operation must be admitted into the grammar, and ideally it would be via join. So in the monoids I take it you are saying that we can express the union operation via $\bigstar$, instead of stipulating that some binary branching trees can be interpreted via the operation of union. Basically, monads are used by linguists to avoid stipulating extra rules for interpreting binary branching trees